# How to draw a node group in a layout panel using python

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, properties

I just made that node group and i just wanted that this node group should appear in Properties panel in 3d view which appears when 'N' Key is Pressed 
this should look like this in materials tab

[image: screenshot]
can any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: This sounds confusing. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5cxs.png)??

Comment: From you edit, I see that you have added  a custom panel in the 3D view. That information is important I think. You should add it back again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already gave you a answer to this here https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-access-and-draw-the-node-group-input-slider-in-layout-panel/1185331/12

You had a material named "TestMat" and a group named "Group". It draws the group properties if there is a material and group with those names.

[image]